# In Oracle eBS forms, how do I reverse engineer what the specific table names are?

Tags: sql, oracle

I am using the Oracle app iprocurement, and I want to verify things I see in the backend database. So I may be on a Requisition page in Oracle forms, and I want to see how it is stored in the Db.   My colleague says I can use the option `Help --> Diagnostics --> Examine` , but I'm not seeing how this helps :

I get this picture :

[image]
but how do I then go back into the database and locate what this is? Is the table called `NAVIGATOR` here ? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Use** **`Help -->Record History`**

Yes, the navigation, `Help --> Diagnostics --> Examine`, does enable you to see information about the Oracle Application form’s code block (one can open the form’s code and examine the block and determine record information in this manner).

More often than not, I just navigate to`Help --> Record History`.

Before I do anything, I enable diagnostics for my profile.
Navigate as follows: `System Administrator>Profile>Personal`
In the Find System Profile Values dialog box, search for “FND: Diagnostics” enter and save “Yes” for the User Value.

[image]

Next I navigate to a form.  On the Forms menu, select Help and Record History:

[image]

You will then see the database record history.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend you start with `Help --> Record History`

If available (not all forms/records support it) it will tell you the name of the table (or view) containing the current record.  `Help --> Diagnostics --> Examine` will show you the contents of the current field (it's value), the field's name and which form block it exists in.  There's no guaranteed mapping from form blocks to database tables or views, so while it may at times be helpful, much of the time it's not.

You can, however, open the form in Forms Builder find the named form block (determined by inspecting `Help --> Diagnostics --> Examine`) and eventually figure out which queries and code blocks populate the form blocks and fields of interest.

To know what form you need to inspect with Forms Bulider you can use `Help --> About Oracle Applications` while viewing the desired form.  The form name will be listed in the `Current Form` section.